# how to remove index.php from all website url

Tags: magento-enterprise, index

My website name is `wizer.in` my website issue is each & every page of our website have index.php extension Like contact us page url is look like

wizer.in/index.php/contact-us.html

Please tell me the process to remove index.php from all urls of Megento website.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your backend and do the following,

```
System->Configuration->General->Web
```

Now on the ***Search Engines Optimization*** tab select yes for Use Web Server Rewrites

Answer (score 0):

To remove `index.php` from URLs follow the below steps :

1. Log-in Magento Admin
2. Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web`
3. From *Search Engine Optimisation* tab **Use Web Server Rewrites** select **YES**.
4. Make sure your *Secure* and *Unsecure* base urls should end with **“/”**.
5. Now edit your `.htaccess` ( will be in magento root folder ) and paste the code which is given at **[this link](http://magentomonsters.com/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls-in-magento/)**

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps :

1) Go to System -> Configuration -> Web 
2) From Search Engine Optimisation tab Use Web Server Rewrites select YES.

The final step involves creating/editing a .htaccess file in the Magento installation folder and this will actually rewrite the URLs. Choose the applicable .htaccess version below.

**If your Magento store is installed in root (public_html), use this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**If your Magento store is installed in a subfolder (public_html/magento), use this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magento/index.php [L]
```

It's Done.